# How can I draw text on a haskell chart graphics?

Tags: haskell, haskell-diagrams

I would like to draw some label besides points on a XY chart drawn using Chart with diagrams backend in Haskell. Eg. I have data like:

`data = [("foo", 1,2), ("bar", 1, 3), ... ]`

and would like to draw labels `foo` and `bar` at or near coordinates (1,2) and (1,3) respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [PlotAnnotation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart-1.1/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Chart-Plot-Annotation.html).  Something like:

`toPlot $ def & plot_annotation_values .~ [(1, 2, "foo"), (1, 3, "bar"), ... ]`

Comment: Thanks. It works but I am still puzzled on how to configure font attributes... Will have to look a little bit more into it. Could you please tell me where you took that knowledge from? I was not able to find documents on the wiki site and the featured examples do not plot annotations (AFAICT).

Comment: I just went to Hackage and browsed the per-module docs there.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and answer. Will try to be less impatient and search more thoroughly next time...

Comment: No worries.  It took me a long time to get used to Haskell's current state of documentation for (almost) every function, but few tutorials.

Comment: Well, it is just that Chart is large and I did not have much time. But having been programming Haskell for more than ten years, I am quite aware that documentation, examples and practical tutorials are not always valued... But this is overgeneralisation.